# What are the names of all released versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, ppa, deb

I'm working on an icon theme for GTK+ and I'm creating package in PPA and I want to know all the names of Ubuntu for packages.

So far I've created deb packages for

- oneiric
- natty
- maverick
- lucid

Comment: The codenames ("Oneiric Ocelot", "Natty Narwhal", etc) are only supposed to be used in development. On the website and on official documentation, the names should be "Ubuntu 11.10", "Ubuntu 11.04", etc.

Comment: @Flimm That may have been the original intention, but that's not how it's been used.  10.04 is referred to as "Lucid" just about everywhere, and even as far back as Hardy Heron, its default desktop background was a [stylized heron](http://www.lucidtips.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/ubuntu-804-lts-hardy-heron-on-compaq-evo-n610c_desktop1.png)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the development code names can be found on the following ubuntu-wiki:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames

Since you are building packages, the *supported versions* that you can build for are described on your launchpad PPA:

[image: pic]

Since you are building debs - adjust the name of the target in your debian/changelog file:

[image: pic2]

Convention is that target names are lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

There is an up-to-date List of releases at **[Releases – Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)** which contains information about current, future, and end of life releases. It also shows the Release date and the End of Life date of each release.

[image]
...
**↓**

Comment: This link provides a list that is more updated:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/